# Grafana with InfluxDB: Ad hoc filter is always empty

Tags: grafana, influxdb, adhoc-queries

Data source query language: Flux

Grafana Version 7.4.3

InfluxDB 2.0.4

Can anyone explain how does `Ad hoc filter` work? How is drop down list generated?
In my case it always says `No options found`:

[image]

Variable settings:
[image]

Do I have to write appropriate queries in panels to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have missed info `This datasource does not support adhoc filter yet` when you was creating variable:

[image]

So adhoc filter doesn't work for InfluxDB in your current Grafana version.
BTW: it was supported in previous version (at least 6.7.X).

Comment: In my case it says "Adhoc filters are applied automatically to all queries that target this datasource ". Maybe your InfluxDB version is different?